# Deployment of Azure Landing Zone takes long time

Tags: azure

I am using the following command to deploy the ALZ:

`az deployment mg create --name $NAME --location $LOCATION --management-group-id $managementGroupId --template-file $TEMPLATEFILE --parameters "$PARAMETERS"`

This deployment takes 50 minutes. This is the ALZ that I am deploying
https://github.com/Azure/ALZ-Bicep/

I am deploying the following resources:

- Management Groups
- Custom Policy Definitions
- Custom Role Definitions
- Logging, Automation & Sentinel
- Hub-Networking
- Role Assignments for Management Groups & Subscriptions
- Orchestration - Place All Subscriptions Into ALZ Management Group Hierarchy
- ALZ Default Policy Assignments

Whatever change that I make this takes in total 50mins. Can this time be reduced and if yes - how?

Just to mention, whatif for the same job takes 18-20mins, which is also a lot.